# How to remove the error Method 'Range' of object '-Worksheet' failed while running following VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to code vlookup values in a sheet but the table array is in a different sheet. I am getting this run time error at line 
"Set DataRange = Sourcesheet.Range(StartPoint, DownCel)".

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
Dim Filepath As Variant, SetRange As Range, DataRange As Range, StartPoint 
As Range
Dim LastCol As Long, DownCel As Long, NewRange As String
Dim Sourcesheet As Worksheet, wb2 As Workbook, wb As Workbook

Filepath = Application.GetOpenFilename
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Filepath)
Set Sourcesheet = wb2.Worksheets("Gold_Pending")

Set StartPoint = Sourcesheet.Range("F2")
DownCel = StartPoint.End(xlDown).Row
Set DataRange = Sourcesheet.Range(StartPoint, DownCel)

NewRange = wb2.Name & "!" & DataRange.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

With wb.Sheets("GoldPending")

Range("G2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=VLOOKUP(RC[-7],NewRange,1,0)"
Range("G2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What are the values of StartPoint, DownCel when it fails? If either are zero then it will fail. Though not sure DownCel can be zero in context of what you have written.

Comment: You also never Set wb  in the above. And note in your failing line you are relying on a default member call to the Range variable which if contains an invalid value e.g. 0 or text that cannot be implicitly converted to numeric within range of available rows, or indeed if empty, will fail.

Comment: Thank you for highlighting. I modified my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you don't have a "full/complete" range in:

```
Range(StartPoint, DownCel)
```

Breaking down the parts:

```
Set StartPoint = Sourcesheet.Range("F2") 'This one will give you the starting point of your range i.e. both Column ("F") and Row ("2") location.
DownCel = StartPoint.End(xlDown).Row 'This will only give you "last" row (lets say 13).
```

Therefore you are currently writing:

```
Sourcesheet.Range(StartPoint, DownCel) => Sourcesheet.Range("F2", 13).
```

Change to:

```
Sourcesheet.Range(StartPoint, DownCel) => Sourcesheet.Range(StartPoint, "F" & DownCel)
```

---

Example code to illustrate:

```
Sub test()
Dim StartPoint As Range
Dim DataRange As Range

Set Sourcesheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set StartPoint = Sourcesheet.Range("F2")
DownCel = StartPoint.End(xlDown).Row
Set DataRange = Sourcesheet.Range(StartPoint, "F" & DownCel)

DataRange.Select 'To visualize what Datarange will select

End Sub
```

---

EDIT using "`With`" in two ways:

```
Sub test()
Dim StartPoint As Range
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim wb As Workbook 'Alternative 1 & 2
Dim sht As Worksheet 'Alternative 1
Dim ws As Worksheet


Set Sourcesheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'Alternative 1 & 2
Set sht = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Alternative 1


Set StartPoint = Sourcesheet.Range("F2")
DownCel = StartPoint.End(xlDown).Row
Set DataRange = Sourcesheet.Range(StartPoint, "F" & DownCel)

DataRange.Select 'To visualize what Datarange will select



With sht 'Alternative 1
With wb.Worksheets("GoldPending") 'Alternative 2

'Do stuff...

End With
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining like this. It's crystal clear. I did the modification and now the code is working fine till there.

Comment: But now I am getting an error "Subscript out of range"    at                                 
     With wb.Sheets("GoldPending"). I tried by changing the name of the sheet, but it's not working.

Comment: you declare wb2 ( `Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Filepath)` ). In the same way you need to declare wb ( `Set wb = Workbooks("Book1.xlsx")` ).

Comment: I tested the code by using  set wb = Activeworkbook . I also set it the way you mentioned. But It is still giving me subscript out of range error.

Comment: I think easiest would be Replace: `With wb.Sheets("GoldPending")` -> `With wb.Worksheets("GoldPending")`. But you could actually do it in two ways. I have updated my answer two show you two alternative ways.

Comment: Thank you so much for this help. I am really new to VBA and you really helped me a lot. Thanks again! @wizhi